# Is it possible to create and organize gists in different folders in github?

Tags: github, gist

I'm creating gists for the first time to embed code in my medium article, and would like to organize gists in different folders with different private / public settings.

I've tried to click on the link to create new gist on github profile from right upper corner, but couldn't find any options to create / put in certain folder.

I've googled and researched elsewhere, but could not find any instructions on organizing them into folders. Sorry if it's a basic question, but appreciate any help!

Comment: Not sure if this would be allowed, but maybe you can try by putting a `/` in the filename and cloning locally and seeing if it ends up a subdirectory. Like perhaps make a gist with a file `test/test.txt` with any content and see what you get when you clone it. I might try this later but it would be as quick for you to check as for me.

Comment: I've just tried it, but it said "Contents files can't be in subdirectories or include '/' in the name"... thanks for the idea tho!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not yet available (mid 2019)

- In [March 2019](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-03-13-pinned-gists/), you can pin your gists to your profile
- In [May 2019](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-05-08-gist-notifications/), you can receive notifications for new conversations occurring on gists

So maybe Gist will still evolve soon.

Comment: Hmm so as of now, there is no way of private and public gists co-existing under one github account??

Comment: Yes, they can, but not as separate folders.

Comment: Thanks, that just did what I needed to do !